# Retrieve facebook photos uploaded by me

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api, photo

Is there any ways to retrieve facebook photos uploaded by myself only? I don't need to retrieve photos that are uploaded by others.

```
photos = facebookClient.fetchConnection("me/photos", Photo.class);
List<com.restfb.types.Photo> photosList = photos.getData();
```

I am doing it for my jsp page and using RestFB library.

Comment: Are you getting any error? Where are you stuck at?

Comment: The coding is working fine, but it will retrieve all the photos tagged with me (uploaded by my friends). But all need is photos uploaded by me only.

Answer (score 0):

Use FQL to get only your photos:

```
String query = 
"SELECT pid, src, src_small, src_big, caption FROM photo WHERE owner=" + yourUid;

List<JsonObject> queryResults = 
facebookClient.executeFqlQuery(query, JsonObject.class);

for(int i=0; i<queryResults.size(); i++)
{
    String photoUrl = queryResults.get(i).getString("src"); 
    // add your code to use photoUrl
}
```

And the you can iterate through queryResults to get src for each image.

Comment: I tried that in the Graph API Explorer and it works. Can I ask if I am able to iterate those data in jsp page? `<c:forEach items="${photosList}" var="photo">` How should I retrieve the src of the photo?

Comment: I have updated the code. Please check. You can add photoUrl to photoList inside for loop and use that in JSP.

Comment: I realized there is a limit to 100 objects. `List<JsonObject> photosList = facebookClient.executeFqlQuery(query, JsonObject.class, Parameter.with("limit", 200));` Even though I set it to 200, it still retrieve only 100, any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `me/photos/uploaded`, which does exactly what you want.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/user/photos/

```
photos = facebookClient.fetchConnection("me/photos/uploaded", Photo.class);     
List<com.restfb.types.Photo> photosList = photos.getData();
```